# Unable to convert data stream from AJAX response to CSV file

Tags: arrays, ajax, csv, blob, xlsx

I'm trying to convert the ajax response, which is a stream of data with some junk characters (may be a blob or byte stream or byte array not sure) to csv file. In the downloaded file also I'm getting the same junk data.

```
$.ajax({
  url: requestUrl,
  type: "POST",
  async: false,
  data: data_request_clientside,
  contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'text',
  success: function (response) {
    var binary = "";
            var responseTextLen = response.length;

            for ( i = 0; i < responseTextLen; i++ ) {
                binary += String.fromCharCode(response.charCodeAt(i) & 255);
            }
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = "data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml;base64," + btoa(binary);
            a.download = 'workingStuff.csv';
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            a.remove();
  },
  error: function (error) {
    console.log("Something went wrong", error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
            var blob = new Blob([csvString]);
        if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob)  // IE hack; see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh779016.aspx
            window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, "filename.csv");
        else
        {
            var a = window.document.createElement("a");
            a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob, {type: "text/plain"});
            a.download = "filename.csv";
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();  // IE: "Access is denied"; see: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/797361/ie-10-treats-blob-url-as-cross-origin-and-denies-access
            document.body.removeChild(a);
        }
```

just put the code under the successsfunction and modify little according to your need, this is untested yet

Comment: Thanks for the help!! I tried this already, this is also giving data in junk only ... I'm still working on it, just came to know the response is an encoded data -Transfer-Encoding chunked. Trying to find the decoding for the same.